# How to stop paper feeding when using PrintForm to print

Tags: .net, vb.net, printing, zebra-printers, printform

I am using [PrintForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.printing.printform%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to print a snapshot of the current form to a [Dot Matrix Printer](http://www.tvs-e.in/product.aspx?pid=10). It is printing fine, however the printer scrolls the entire the paper roll after printing. It is supposed to stop at the end of printing.

Code to print the form:

```
PrintForm1.Print()
```

How do I tell the printer to stop paper feeding once the printing is complete?

Comment: Go in the printer properties and select a paper size as the default.

Comment: @HansPassant My paper size is 5" wide. This size isn't available in the printer properties.

Comment: If there is no option to set a height then you'll need a better printer driver, one that can handle the way Windows prints pages.  Contact the printer manufacturer for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PrinterSettings property of PrintForm, we can change the paper size to the way we want. The printer will stop feeding the paper once it reaches the mentioned height.

```
        Dim customSize As New PaperSize("Custom", 500, Me.Height)
        PrintForm1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = customSize
        PrintForm1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = 0
        PrintForm1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = 0
        PrintForm1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom = 50
        PrintForm1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = 0
        PrintForm1.Print()
```